# UITapGestureRecognizer not doing anything

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I've got an app that displays a page of text with the ability to tap a button or swipe in a view to advance or retreat through various pages. The container view has two UISwipeGestureRecognizers attached, for swipe left and swipe right. No trouble with these gestures. But now I'm trying to add UITapGestureRecognizer to another view, providing an ability similar to iBooks or the Kindle app, tap the left to go back, the right to go forward. Nothing I do can get the gesture to fire. No hint that it is ever being triggered, even if I put the gesture on my topmost view and disable other gestures.

The view controller implements UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, though I've not needed to implement delegate methods. I did try implementing shouldReceiveTouch: without success.

Here's a snippet of code where I create and attach the gesture recognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureTurnPage:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];
```

Comment: Could you please show more code?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `tapGestureTurnPage:` gets triggered?

Comment: xissburg, I understand more code would be helpful, but not sure what I would show. This is a completed app, I'm just adding some tweaks now for an update. Not sure which code might help indicate where the problem lies.

Comment: PengOne, no, it never gets triggered. The tap gesture never fires. Right now the only code in tapGestureTurnPage is a call to NSLog and nothing ever shows up. If that method fired then I wouldn't be posting here. :)

Comment: Chris Roberts, show how your view tree is organized, and what kind of events each of these views respond for (gestures and other stuff).

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't get called on the topmost view?

Comment: xissburg, your question triggered a thought and I see what's happening. Forgot about some special touch events being grabbed by my UIWebView. I'm not using gestures to watch for those, so it didn't occur to me that there could be a conflict, but I think that's what's causing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Try this on the view you're adding the gesture recognizers:

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: I was stuck on this for hours.  Thank you!!!      Actually you can set the user interaction enabled in the Story Board as well.   But this was the issue for me

Comment: a thousand upvotes for you, sir! I too was spending hours to no avail before this.

Comment: Swift 3: view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true. Also worth noting that you might need to enable user interaction on the parent view if you're adding gesture recognizers to a subview.

Comment: Also check that you actually called `addGestureRecognizer` to the correct view. It does not have to be the same as the view supplied to `initWithTarget`. So in the end there are 3 things to check (1) initWithTarget, (2) addGestureRecognizer, (3) isUserInteractionEnabled.

Answer (score 7):

You mention that you've tried this, but just in case go through it again.

Try using the delegate with `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` in the header and then setting the delegate:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureTurnPage:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
recognizer.delegate = self;
[recognizer release];
```

Then implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return YES;
}
```

Then use a debugger or toss an `NSLog` into the above method and also `tapGestureTurnPage:` to see if these methods are being called.

Comment: PengOne, I've got a method virtually identical to this already in place.

Comment: @Chris: Then you're going to have to show more code if you want help with this. Are there subviews in the way?

Comment: As it turns out, there are. As noted in comments above, I realized the problem is being caused by taps intercepted by a UIWebView.

Comment: Not exactly solved, but I'm pointed in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add this where you initialize the gesture:

```
recognizer.delegate = self;
```

and add this in the "self" class:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

This allows me to have gestures recognized on the UIWebView, and the UIWebView will still respond to the taps. (which i wanted - you may not)