# iOS Swift GestureRecognizer not working

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I try to Recognize User Taps on a View.
I tried it with the following Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


    let request = NSURLRequest(URL:URL!)
    self.webView.loadRequest(request)
    self.webView.delegate = self;

}

func doubleTapped(gesture:UIGestureRecognizer)) {
    // do something cool here
    print("tabbed")
}
```

But nothing happens, the Method doubleTapped is never called. Whats wrong here?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/q/6475908/6309 help?

Answer (score 0):

GestureRecognizer on main view will work in your case if there is no subviews.

You can add the tap Gesture to the topmost view if the subviews have same frame as main view to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: how do I find which view is the topmost?

Comment: Normally the the view you have added in last is on the top. But if you have use z-index then highest z-index view will on the top. 

This link might help you:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6